# How to run function after last function is finished in loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Below is my code

```
var request = require("request");

$('.xxx').siblings().each(function(i, elem) {
        if (i === $('.xxx').siblings().length - 1) {
            goToOrderDetail(true, i);
        }
    });

function goToOrderDetail(status, i) {

    console.log('Processing' + i + 'data!');

    var options = {
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://example.com"
    }

    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(response);
    }
}
```

When I run this file on node.js, I will get message like below in my terminal.

```
Processing 1 data!
Processing 2 data!
Processing 3 data!
Processing 4 data!
Processing 5 data!
response message
response message
response message
response message
response message
```

But what I expect and want is

```
Processing 1 data!
response message
Processing 2 data!
response message
Processing 3 data!
response message
Processing 4 data!
response message
Processing 5 data!
response message
```

I know this is about sync or async issue, but How can I fix it?

How can I wait the goToOrderDetail function finished and then keep loop next element?

I did looked for async([enter link description here](http://caolan.github.io/async/index.html)) package but have no idea which function I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running well, but your `console.log` do not represent what is happening.

If you move your `console.log` like this

```
var options = {
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://example.com"
}

request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log('Processing' + i + 'data!');
    console.log("test");
}
```

you will get

```
Processing 1 data!
test
Processing 2 data!
test
Processing 3 data!
test
Processing 4 data!
test
Processing 5 data!
test
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you want to do, or even how your function can get called that many times with the `if(i === ...)`that you put there. One way to really ensure that your requests really are called in a synchronous way is to "chain" them. It has the added benefit to state more clearly what you intend...

The following (not tested) code illustrates what I mean. Keep in mind that you lose the benefit of running parallel requests.

```
var request = require("request");
var numberOfRequests = $(".xxx").length;

function goToOrderDetail(status, index, maximum) {
  console.log('Preparing' + index + 'th request!');
  var options = {
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://example.com"
  }

  request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log("received " + index +"th request response : ");
    console.log(response);
    //here, the request is done. maybe we want to launch another one
    if(index < maximum )
      goToOrderDetail(status, index +1, maximum);
  }
}
//call the function once, for the first request, and let the chaining happen
goToOrderDetail(true, 1, numberOfRequests);
```